# Flexbox Justify Content: Right not applying

Tags: html, css, wordpress, sass, flexbox

I am trying to align my footer using flexbox and for some reason, it won't push it all the way to the right.

When using `justify-content: center` it will center the items but when I try to use `justify-content: right` it pushes all of the list items back to the left. I tried making the width of the box 100% but that didn't work either.

Here is some of the code I am using.

```css
.site-footer {
  position: relative;
  a {
    color: blue;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
}

.social-footer-nav{
  ul{
    display: flex;
    list-style-type: none;
  }
}

.footer-nav{
  ul{
    display: flex;
    list-style-type: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<footer id="colophon" class="site-footer">
    <div class="site-info">
        <nav class="social-footer-nav">
            <?php
            wp_nav_menu( array(
                'theme_location' => 'social',
                'menu_id'        => 'social-menu',
            ) );
            ?>
        </nav>
    </div>
<footer
```

Comment: to add to @zgood's comment, https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: sorry I deleted my comment... it was "I don't think you want `justify-content: right` I think you want `justify-content: flex-end`". I deleted it because I saw [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content) that they list `right` as a valid value.

Comment: @zgood yeah that's what I just figured out. Clearly not thinking straight! Thanks for the reminder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly just a overlooked option. There is a`justify-content: right` but it does not push content in the flexbox to the right. To achieve content on the right side, `justify-content: flex-end` must be used.

Comment: [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content#Values) lists `right` as a valid value... but I have never used it - I use `flex-end`. Maybe that value was from an older spec.... I dunno